# After text widget opens, tkinter GUI crashes/does not respond whenever its closed

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Right now, after I press the 'Time Range' button and call the calculateTime function, the text widget would appear with the results that I've inserted into it. However, after that, whenever I close the GUI window, the program would freeze and I'll have to forced quit it. This is my code:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
import math
from tkinter import messagebox


class MyClass(tkinter.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tkinter.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        #Setting up frame and widgets

        vcmd1 = (self.register(self.__vcmd1), '%P', '%S')
        vcmd2 = (self.register(self.__vcmd2), '%P')
        vcmd3 = (self.register(self.__vcmd3), '%P', '%S')

        label_iso = Label(self,text="Isotope A, Element")
        label_vol = Label(self, text="Voltage")
        label_range = Label(self, text="Charge Range")

        label_iso.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=E)
        label_vol.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=E)
        label_range.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=E)

        self.entry1 = tkinter.Entry(self, validate="key", validatecommand=vcmd1)
        self.entry2 = tkinter.Entry(self, validate="key", validatecommand=vcmd2)
        self.entry3 = tkinter.Entry(self, validate="key", validatecommand=vcmd3)

        self.entry1.grid(row=0, column=1)
        self.entry2.grid(row=1, column=1)
        self.entry3.grid(row=2, column=1)

    def __vcmd1(self, P, S):
        validString = 'qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmQWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM,1234567890'
        if not S in validString:
            return False
        if "," in P:
            if (len(P) - 1) > len(P.replace(",","")):
                return False
                messagebox.showinfo("Error", "Expected Form: ex. 133,Cs")
        else:
            return True

    def __vcmd2(self, P):
        if P == '':
            return True
        try:
            float(P)
            return True
        except ValueError:
            messagebox.showinfo("Error", "Entry is not a float or integer")
            return False


    def __vcmd3(self, P, S):
        if "," in P:
            if len(P.split(",")) > 2:
                return False
            a = P.split(",")[0]
            b = P.split(",")[1]
            if a != '' and b != '':
                try:
                    int(a)
                    int(b)
                except ValueError:
                    messagebox.showinfo("Error", "Expected form: ex. 1,12")
                    return False
        else:
            return True

class TimeGenerator:

    def __init__(self,master):

        frame = MyClass(master)
        frame.grid(columnspan=2)

        button = Button(root, text='Time Range', command=self.calculateTime)
        button.grid(row=3, columnspan=2)

        self.text = Text(root)
        self.iso = frame.entry1
        self.vol = frame.entry2
        self.r = frame.entry3

    def calculateTime(self):
        x = 5
        if self.r.get() == "" or self.iso.get() == "" or self.vol.get() == "":
            messagebox.showinfo("Error", "No field can be empty")
            return None

        self.iso = self.iso.get().replace(" ", "")
        list = []
        for e in self.iso.split(","):
            list.append(e)

        f = open("/Users/LazyLinh/PycharmProjects/mass.mas12.txt", "r")
        i = 0
        while (i < 40):
            header = f.readline()
            i += 1
        self.mass = 0

        #iterate through text file

        for line in f:
            line = line.strip()
            columns = line.split()
            if (list[0] == columns[3]):
                if (list[1].lower() == columns[4].lower()):
                    if (len(columns) == 16):
                        self.mass = float(columns[13].replace("#","")) + float(columns[14].replace("#",""))
                    else:
                        self.mass = float(columns[12].replace("#","")) + float(columns[13].replace("#",""))

        #Calculation
        self.r = self.r.get().replace(" ", "")
        tup = tuple(int(x) for x in self.r.split(","))

        list = []
        for q in range(tup[0], tup[1] + 1):
            y = (x * math.sqrt(self.mass * 1.6605402e-27 / (2 * q * float(self.vol.get())))) * 10e6
            list.append(y)
        i = tup[0]

        #inserting to text widget
        for time in list:
            self.text.insert("end", "%d: %s\n" % (i, time))
            i = i + 1
        self.text.pack()

root = Tk()
b = TimeGenerator(root)
root.mainloop()
```

I've tried to searched up on this topic, but I'm not really using any weird update() function, and text shows up after the function is finished, so how likely that it is an event loop problem? Am I also doing something wrong that could cause this problem?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have widgets in the root window that use both `pack` and `grid`. You cannot do this. Within a given container (root window, frame, etc) you can use one or the other, but not both.

The reason your program freezes is due to `pack` and `grid` fighting to gain control of the layout. When you pack the text widget it causes a change in the size and/or position of other widgets in the root window. That triggers `grid` to try to re-layout the widgets it is responsible for. This triggers `pack` to try to re-layout the widgets it is responsible for, and on and on until the end of time.

My guess is that you need to use `grid` with `self.text` since you use `grid` everywhere else.